# Does Audit.NET EF work with EF Core 2.1, and specifically ambient transactions

Tags: entity-framework-core-2.1, audit.net

Just stumbled on this library (EF version) and looks very good.  Just wondering if this is currently compatible with EF Core 2.1 as well as ambient transactions.  I see that there is a onScopeCreated / onScopeSaving to handle transactions.  Will this even be necessary if involved within an ambient transaction?

Comment: Note that OnScopeCreated / OnScopeSaving virtual methods refers to the Audit.NET's `AuditScope` object, not a TransactionScope. also I haven't run any test against EF core 2.1. It should work to the extent of the EF library being backward compatible. Otherwise you can [open a new Issue](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/new/choose) and I will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Audit.NET](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET) / [Audit.EntityFramework](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/tree/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework) now supports EF Core 2.1 and ambient transactions. Please upgrade your references and re-test. If you're still having problems, please [open a new issue](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/new/choose).

Support was added on version 12.1.10

Comment: Thanks, will give it a go with your latest!